# Functional testing Laravel ViewComposer

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I am trying to test controllers in Laravel using the standard set up this works fine. The test below passes.

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {



/**
 * A basic functional test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicExample()
{

    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
}
```

However once I introduce a ViewComposer - registered with a ServiceProvider

```
class MenuComposer {

const NONE = 0;
const READWRITE = 1;
const READONLY = 2;




/**
 * constructor largely for testing purposes
 * @param View $view
 * @param Auth $auth
 */
public function __construct()
{



}

public function compose($view)
{
    $access = $this->getAccessLevel();

    $view->with('menuItems',$this->menuItems($access));

}
```

The production code works as expected - but the test fails because it 
** ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /srv/host_share/sds/app/views/hello.blade.php)
 **

So the $view variable passed into the compose method is null/empty ? Can anyone suggest what I could do to make tests run and continue to use the viewcomposer functionality?

Comment: Seeing your entire exception message would help -- is it that `$view` has no object, or something about the testing environment prevents $access or objects returned by `menuItems` to not be an object?

Comment: See edit - it is just referring to the blade template - I am thinking it is $view has no object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error, Laravel's telling you this "Trying to get property of non-object" happens inside the following blade template

> (View: /srv/host_share/sds/app/views/hello.blade.php)

It probably means you're passing the view a variable (like `menuItems`), and then trying to get a property on that variable

```
$menuItems->some_prop
$another_var->some_prop
```

I'd comments out every property access in the view, and add each one back until the error reoccurs.  Once you've figured out **which** view variable isn't an object, you can debug why the testing environment doesn't properly populate it with an object.

Comment: thanks - the viewComposer populates an @include and removing that which contains just one variable makes the test pass - however obviously that is still needed in the composer $this->menuItems

Comment: Turns out it was an issue mocking the auth facade - but this led me down the right path so +1